# Saw Blade Arbor Hole Enlargement

Tags: table-saw, saw-blade

I have a new SCM table saw with a 30mm arbor. I need to get a machinist to enlarge a 5/8 arbor hole on my good blades for use on this saw. Do they make it precisely 30mm or is there normally some tolerance there?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to obtain a blade that fits the saw and measure that.

Comment: Is the machinist a friend (so you can avail of 'mates rates')? If not this may not even make economic sense. Plus the elephant in the room: could you be certain the enlargement is done with absolute precision, and/or won't result in any distortion?

Comment: Re. tolerances, if you have an accurate calipers you can get a good idea from your existing blades. Take multiple measurements of each hole to rule out individual measurement errors and then, are they all the same, if not how much variation are you seeing, and what's the maximum? You could also measure the new saw's arbor to see how close it is to 30mm exactly. But based on general observations of saw blades and machinists' fits blades are a sliding fit on arbors, but chatter online suggests there is surprisingly high variation (even from blades from one manufacturer).

Comment: I was hoping that there was some standard but it makes sense that that there is considerable variation. I guess it's not surprising that even with the same manufacturer it can vary given that most production is outsourced to other countries and probably not all the same ones! I'll get a blade designed that is designed for the saw and measure it, thanks much!